# Odoo Pass a dynamic list to View

Tags: view, filter, odoo, odoo-8

I want to filter many2one field using a domain in the create view. What I'm trying is send a list to the view as a functional field and use it in the domain. (That list will change according to user) It will look as follows,

```
<field name="filter_ids" invisible="True"/>
<field name="department_id" domain="[('id','in',filter_ids)]">
```

What type of functional field should I use for this purpose? 
Or any idea to dynamically change (one user to another) the domain of a many2one field?

I tried many ways using on_change, fields_view_get and so many others. On_change calls on load but it doesn't filter values onload. fields_view_get add the domain but it apply for all form views including update view which should not happen according to the requirements.  please help :)

Comment: Try to find text `,'in',` in Odoo addons folder. Maybe you find an example. I tried to find solution, but all in vane. ((

Answer (score 0):

1-You can use fields_view_get then

2- set  
 so you don't get the field in your edit view

3- use another field which should behave as you want it on the edit view